# Error Reference to undeclared resource - Trying to get terraform modules to work

Tags: terraform

New terraform learner here, trying to learn by example and by coding. I was looking for terraform modules that would allow one to create a VM, found the example here https://faun.pub/creating-a-windows-vm-in-azure-using-terraform-which-way-is-best-13aff3ed9b74 which I thought would take my very basic terraform knowledge up a notch, since creating a VM is a process I am familiar with and can build upon. The experience has been nothing but frustrating. This is my 3rd week on it, and it still feels like miles away.

I read up the first solution and my files are structured in exactly thesame way as described.Mind, I have tried the first method, and it was riddled with errors, so I decided to try the second method which was supposed to be simpler.

I created a folder called simple_vm and inside it, another folder called vm.

Here are the contents.

vm_module_local_example.tf

```
# Create an Azure VM cluster with Terraform calling a Module. Creates 1 for Windows 10 desktop and 1 for Windows 2019 Server.
module windows_desktop_vm_using_local_module {
source              = "./vm"
resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
location            = "uksouth"
sloc                = "uks"
vm_subnet_id        = module.network.vnet_subnets[0]
vm_name             = "tfdtlocmod"
vm_size             = var.desktop_vm_size
publisher           = var.desktop_vm_image_publisher
offer               = var.desktop_vm_image_offer
sku                 = var.desktop_vm_image_sku
static_ip_address   = "10.0.1.15"
activity_tag        = "Windows Desktop"
admin_password      = module.vmpassword.secretvalue
}
module windows_server_vm_using_local_module {
source              = "./vm"
resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
location            = "uksouth"
sloc                = "uks"
vm_subnet_id        = module.network.vnet_subnets[1]
vm_name             = "tfsvlocmod"
vm_size             = var.server_vm_size
publisher           = var.server_vm_image_publisher
offer               = var.server_vm_image_offer
sku                 = var.server_vm_image_sku
static_ip_address   = "10.0.2.15"
activity_tag        = "Windows Server"
admin_password      = module.vmpassword.secretvalue
}
```

Within the folder called VM. I have the following files.

main.tf

```
resource "random_string" "nic_prefix" {
length  = 4
special = false
}
resource "azurerm_network_interface" "vm_nic" {
name                = "${var.vm_name}-nic1"
location            = var.location
resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
ip_configuration {
name                          = "${var.vm_name}_nic_${random_string.nic_prefix.result}"
subnet_id                     = var.vm_subnet_id
private_ip_address_allocation = "Static"
private_ip_address            = var.static_ip_address
}
tags = var.tags
}
resource "azurerm_network_interface_security_group_association" "vm_nic_sg" {
network_interface_id      = azurerm_network_interface.vm_nic.id
network_security_group_id = var.network_security_group_id
count                     = var.network_security_group_id == "" ? 0 : 1
}
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine" "windows_vm" {
name                = var.vm_name
vm_size             = var.vm_size
location            = var.location
resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
tags = merge(var.tags, { activityName = "${var.activity_tag} " })
network_interface_ids = [
"${azurerm_network_interface.vm_nic.id}",
]
storage_image_reference {
publisher = var.publisher
offer     = var.offer
sku       = var.sku
version   = "latest"
}
identity {
type = "SystemAssigned"
}
storage_os_disk {
name              = "${var.vm_name}-os-disk"
caching           = "ReadWrite"
create_option     = "FromImage"
managed_disk_type = "Standard_LRS"
}
os_profile {
admin_password = module.vmpassword.secretvalue
admin_username = "azureuser"
computer_name  = var.vm_name
}
os_profile_windows_config {
provision_vm_agent = true
}
delete_os_disk_on_termination    = var.vm_os_disk_delete_flag
delete_data_disks_on_termination = var.vm_data_disk_delete_flag
}
```

outputs.tf

```
output "vm_id" {
value = "${azurerm_virtual_machine.windows_vm.id}"
}
output "vm_name" {
value = "${azurerm_virtual_machine.windows_vm.name}"
}
output "vm_location" {
value = "${azurerm_virtual_machine.windows_vm.location}"
}
output "vm_resource_group_name" {
value = "${azurerm_virtual_machine.windows_vm.resource_group_name}"
}
```

variables.tf

```
variable "resource_group_name" {
}
variable "location" {
}
variable "sloc" {
}
variable "vm_size" {
default = "Standard_B1s"
}
variable "vm_subnet_id" {
}
variable "vm_name" {
}
variable "vm_os_disk_delete_flag" {
default = true
}
variable "vm_data_disk_delete_flag" {
default = true
}
variable "network_security_group_id" {
default = ""
}
variable "static_ip_address" {
}
variable "publisher" {
}
variable "offer" {
}
variable "sku" {
}
variable "tags" {
type        = map
description = "All mandatory tags to use on all assets"
default = {
activityName       = "AzureVMWindowsDemo"
automation         = "Terraform"
costCenter1        = "A00000"
dataClassification = "Demo"
managedBy          = "example@test.com"
solutionOwner      = "example@test.com"
}
}
variable "activity_tag" {
}
variable "admin_password" {
}
```

Taking what is on the website, I get the following errors.

```
Error: Reference to undeclared resource
│
│   on vm_module_local_example.tf line 4, in module "windows_desktop_vm_using_local_module":
│    4: resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
│
│ A managed resource "azurerm_resource_group" "rg" has not been declared in the root module.
╵
╷
│ Error: Reference to undeclared module
│
│   on vm_module_local_example.tf line 7, in module "windows_desktop_vm_using_local_module":
│    7: vm_subnet_id        = module.network.vnet_subnets[0]
│
│ No module call named "network" is declared in the root module.
╵
╷
│ Error: Reference to undeclared input variable
│
│   on vm_module_local_example.tf line 9, in module "windows_desktop_vm_using_local_module":
│    9: vm_size             = var.desktop_vm_size
│
│ An input variable with the name "desktop_vm_size" has not been declared. This variable can be declared with a variable "desktop_vm_size" {} block.
╵
╷
│ Error: Reference to undeclared input variable
│
│   on vm_module_local_example.tf line 10, in module "windows_desktop_vm_using_local_module":
│   10: publisher           = var.desktop_vm_image_publisher
│
│ An input variable with the name "desktop_vm_image_publisher" has not been declared. This variable can be declared with a variable "desktop_vm_image_publisher" {} block.
╵
╷
│ Error: Reference to undeclared input variable
│
│   on vm_module_local_example.tf line 11, in module "windows_desktop_vm_using_local_module":
│   11: offer               = var.desktop_vm_image_offer
│
│ An input variable with the name "desktop_vm_image_offer" has not been declared. This variable can be declared with a variable "desktop_vm_image_offer" {} block.
╵
╷
│ Error: Reference to undeclared input variable
│
│   on vm_module_local_example.tf line 12, in module "windows_desktop_vm_using_local_module":
│   12: sku                 = var.desktop_vm_image_sku
│
│ An input variable with the name "desktop_vm_image_sku" has not been declared. This variable can be declared with a variable "desktop_vm_image_sku" {} block.
╵
╷
│ Error: Reference to undeclared module
│
│   on vm_module_local_example.tf line 15, in module "windows_desktop_vm_using_local_module":
│   15: admin_password      = module.vmpassword.secretvalue
│
│ No module call named "vmpassword" is declared in the root module.
╵
╷
│ Error: Reference to undeclared resource
│
│   on vm_module_local_example.tf line 19, in module "windows_server_vm_using_local_module":
│   19: resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
│
│ A managed resource "azurerm_resource_group" "rg" has not been declared in the root module.
╵
╷
│ Error: Reference to undeclared module
│
│   on vm_module_local_example.tf line 22, in module "windows_server_vm_using_local_module":
│   22: vm_subnet_id        = module.network.vnet_subnets[1]
│
│ No module call named "network" is declared in the root module.
╵
╷
│ Error: Reference to undeclared input variable
│
│   on vm_module_local_example.tf line 24, in module "windows_server_vm_using_local_module":
│   24: vm_size             = var.server_vm_size
│
│ An input variable with the name "server_vm_size" has not been declared. This variable can be declared with a variable "server_vm_size" {} block.
╵
╷
│ Error: Reference to undeclared input variable
│
│   on vm_module_local_example.tf line 25, in module "windows_server_vm_using_local_module":
│   25: publisher           = var.server_vm_image_publisher
│
│ An input variable with the name "server_vm_image_publisher" has not been declared. This variable can be declared with a variable "server_vm_image_publisher" {} block.
╵
╷
│ Error: Reference to undeclared input variable
│
│   on vm_module_local_example.tf line 26, in module "windows_server_vm_using_local_module":
│   26: offer               = var.server_vm_image_offer
│
│ An input variable with the name "server_vm_image_offer" has not been declared. This variable can be declared with a variable "server_vm_image_offer" {} block.
╵
╷
│ Error: Reference to undeclared input variable
│
│   on vm_module_local_example.tf line 27, in module "windows_server_vm_using_local_module":
│   27: sku                 = var.server_vm_image_sku
│
│ An input variable with the name "server_vm_image_sku" has not been declared. This variable can be declared with a variable "server_vm_image_sku" {} block.
╵
╷
│ Error: Reference to undeclared module
│
│   on vm_module_local_example.tf line 30, in module "windows_server_vm_using_local_module":
│   30: admin_password      = module.vmpassword.secretvalue
│
│ No module call named "vmpassword" is declared in the root module.
```

I can see that a lot of the errors relate to undeclared variables. I then create a variable file as follows (not within the vm folder).

```
variable "subscription_id" {
}
variable "client_id" {
}
variable "client_secret" {
}
variable "tenant_id" {
}
variable "global_settings" {
}
variable "desktop_vm_image_publisher" {
}
variable "desktop_vm_image_offer" {
}
variable "desktop_vm_image_sku" {
}
variable "desktop_vm_image_version" {
}
variable "desktop_vm_size" {
}
variable "server_vm_image_publisher" {
}
variable "server_vm_image_offer" {
}
variable "server_vm_image_sku" {
}
variable "server_vm_image_version" {
}
variable "server_vm_size" {
}
```

created a file called terraform.auto.tfvars.

```
# This file should not be checked into source control (add to .gitignore)
subscription_id = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
client_id       = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
client_secret   = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
tenant_id       = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
## globalsettings
global_settings = {
#Set of tags
tags = {
applicationName = "Windows VM Demo"
businessUnit    = "Technical Solutions"
costCenter      = "MPN Sponsorship"
DR              = "NON-DR-ENABLED"
deploymentType  = "Terraform"
environment     = "Dev"
owner           = "Jack Roper"
version         = "0.1"
}
}
# Desktop VM variables
desktop_vm_image_publisher = "MicrosoftWindowsDesktop"
desktop_vm_image_offer     = "Windows-10"
desktop_vm_image_sku       = "20h1-pro"
desktop_vm_image_version   = "latest"
desktop_vm_size            = "Standard_B1s"
# Server VM Variables
server_vm_image_publisher = "MicrosoftWindowsServer"
server_vm_image_offer     = "WindowsServer"
server_vm_image_sku       = "2019-Datacenter"
server_vm_image_version   = "latest"
server_vm_size            = "Standard_B1s"
```

Running terraform plan this time, I get the following errors.

```
 Error: Reference to undeclared resource
│
│   on vm_module_local_example.tf line 4, in module "windows_desktop_vm_using_local_module":
│    4: resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
│
│ A managed resource "azurerm_resource_group" "rg" has not been declared in the root module.
╵
╷
│ Error: Reference to undeclared module
│
│   on vm_module_local_example.tf line 7, in module "windows_desktop_vm_using_local_module":
│    7: vm_subnet_id        = module.network.vnet_subnets[0]
│
│ No module call named "network" is declared in the root module.
╵
╷
│ Error: Reference to undeclared module
│
│   on vm_module_local_example.tf line 15, in module "windows_desktop_vm_using_local_module":
│   15: admin_password      = module.vmpassword.secretvalue
│
│ No module call named "vmpassword" is declared in the root module.
╵
╷
│ Error: Reference to undeclared resource
│
│   on vm_module_local_example.tf line 19, in module "windows_server_vm_using_local_module":
│   19: resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
│
│ A managed resource "azurerm_resource_group" "rg" has not been declared in the root module.
╵
╷
│ Error: Reference to undeclared module
│
│   on vm_module_local_example.tf line 22, in module "windows_server_vm_using_local_module":
│   22: vm_subnet_id        = module.network.vnet_subnets[1]
│
│ No module call named "network" is declared in the root module.
╵
╷
│ Error: Reference to undeclared module
│
│   on vm_module_local_example.tf line 30, in module "windows_server_vm_using_local_module":
│   30: admin_password      = module.vmpassword.secretvalue
│
│ No module call named "vmpassword" is declared in the root module.
╵
```

Now, It appears I have been extremely unlucky with examples online, in the above there are a lot of missing variables, the author doesnt specify if certain files should be used from a different example (there is a lot of code on the link apparently for different techniques for achieving the same goal). At the same time, I am new to this and wasn't sure if I can truly say there are missing files/details in the solution posted. I have had no luck with contacting the author, no github repo to check that I have the right setup, hence why I have turned here for help. All I want to do is improve my knowledge on terraform modules, I prefer to have explanations and examples so that I can also practice. I could look at git repos, but that would only be giving me solutions without explanation or learning opportunities.

Comment: What is the full error message?

Comment: I have edited the main question to include what I did and the errors I am getting now.

Comment: If the objective is to learn Terraform, then why not go through the Hashi learn tutorials with the providers for platforms you are familiar?

Comment: The example that  you follow is incomplete and incorrect. Forget about it, and find something better. Official TF docs are better.

Comment: Thanks all, I learn better by reading less and practicing more. At least I know its nothing to do with my setup or what I am doing. I will find better examples, preferably one with a step by step guide or a video. I don't understand why anyone would want to post incomplete/incorrect code online.

Answer (score 0):

As people in the comments have mentioned it looks like you are following an incomplete or out of date tutorial. I thought it might help you if I explain how to understand the errors produced so you can tackle this hurdle in future.

```
 Error: Reference to undeclared resource
│
│   on vm_module_local_example.tf line 4, in module "windows_desktop_vm_using_local_module":
│    4: resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
│
│ A managed resource "azurerm_resource_group" "rg" has not been declared in the root module.
╵
```

In the above message Terraform is saying "On line 4 in the file vm_module_local_example.tf, you've set the resource_group_name to be the value of azurerm_resource_group.rg.name but when I tried to find a resource "azure_resource_group" with the name "rg" I couldn't find anything. To fix it you'd need to code up a resource like:

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "rg" {
  name     = "example"
  location = "West Europe"
}
```

Once that's done your line 4 will set `resource_group_name` to be "example".

```
╷
│ Error: Reference to undeclared module
│
│   on vm_module_local_example.tf line 7, in module "windows_desktop_vm_using_local_module":
│    7: vm_subnet_id        = module.network.vnet_subnets[0]
│
│ No module call named "network" is declared in the root module.
```

This is a good one, on line 7 in the file named vm_module_local_example.tf there is a call to module.network.vnet_subnets[0]. So Terraform will look for a module called network before proceeding further. You'd need code like this:

```
module "network" {
   # pass in whatever the module needs...
}
```

Based on the error it looks like the module is expected to contain a resource called vnet_subnets generated with `count` as it's relying on a zero based index (that's the [0] part).

Anyways, hope this helps!